# calcular el iva php

Tags: javascript, php, html

estoy tratando de realizar una importacion desde php a mysql dicha importacion tiene las columnas

```
1   ID Primaria int(11)         No  Ninguna     AUTO_INCREMENT   
2   REFERENCE   varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci     No  Ninguna 
3   CODE    varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci     Sí  NULL            
4   CODETYPE    varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci     Sí  NULL            
5   NAME    varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci     Sí  NULL            
6   PRICEBUY    double          Sí  NULL                
7   PRICESELL
```

entonces necesito que mi columna PRICEBUY
si tiene iva lo sume si no tiene lo deje igual aqui dejo mi codigo de importacion

```
# Cargar clases instaladas por Composer
require_once ("vendor/autoload.php");

# Nuestra base de datos
require_once "bd.php";

# Indicar que usaremos el IOFactory
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

# Obtener conexión o salir en caso de error, mira bd.php
$bd = obtenerBD();

# El archivo a importar
# Recomiendo poner la ruta absoluta si no está junto al script
$rutaArchivo = $_FILES["rutaArchivo"]["tmp_name"];;
var_dump($rutaArchivo);
$documento = IOFactory::load($rutaArchivo);

# Se espera que en la primera hoja estén los productos
$hojaDeProductos = $documento->getSheet(0);

# Preparar base de datos para que los inserts sean rápidos
$bd->beginTransaction();

# Preparar sentencia de productos
$sentencia = $bd->prepare("insert into PRODUCTS2
(REFERENCE, CODE, CODETYPE, NAME, PRICEBUY,PRICESELL) values
(?, ?, ? ,?, ? ,?)");

# Calcular el máximo valor de la fila como entero, es decir, el
# límite de nuestro ciclo
$numeroMayorDeFila = $hojaDeProductos->getHighestRow(); // Numérico
$letraMayorDeColumna = $hojaDeProductos->getHighestColumn(); // Letra
# Convertir la letra al número de columna correspondiente
$numeroMayorDeColumna = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($letraMayorDeColumna);

// Recorrer filas; comenzar en la fila 2 porque omitimos el encabezado
for ($indiceFila = 2; $indiceFila <= $numeroMayorDeFila; $indiceFila++) {

    # Las columnas están en este orden:
    # Código de barras, Descripción, Precio de Compra, Precio de Venta, Existencia
    $REFERENCE = $hojaDeProductos->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $indiceFila);
    $CODE = $hojaDeProductos->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $indiceFila);
    $CODETYPE = $hojaDeProductos->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $indiceFila);
    $NAME = $hojaDeProductos->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $indiceFila);
    $PRICEBUY = $hojaDeProductos->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $indiceFila);
    $PRICESELL = $hojaDeProductos->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $indiceFila);$total = $PRICEBUY * 0.16;

$sentencia->execute([$REFERENCE, $CODE, $CODETYPE, $NAME, $PRICEBUY,$total]);
}

if($sentencia){
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("importado exitosamente");window.location.href="../index.html"</script>';

}
$bd->commit();
```

sume el iva 16% a PRICESELL que seria el precio final
para poder guardar mi importacion dentro de mysql y este se muestre dentro
de un recuadro que tengo para mostrar con un buscador

y aqui muestro el error que me marca

```
string(25) "/opt/lampp/temp/phpUkfJF6"
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell * float in /opt/lampp/htdocs/buscadorlibros/excel_con_mysql-master/importar.php:65 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/buscadorlibros/excel_con_mysql-master/importar.php on line 65
```

Comment: Una regla de normalización de una base de datos es no almacenar valores calculados. Los cálculos se deberían hacer en `Php`.

Comment: y como lo agrego

Comment: @Bicho aunado a lo que dices, se debe almacenar el valor porcentual del IVA en el momento para evitar futuros cambios de Impuestos en algunos rubros

Answer (score 0):

lo resolvi solo tenia que agregar el valor que estuviera dentro de una columna siempre y cuando si tenga un porcentaje

```
if ($PRICEBUY > 0){

    $cnv =(floatval($PRICESELL) * 1.16);

    $sentencia->execute([$REFERENCE, $CODE, $CODETYPE, $NAME, $PRICEBUY,$cnv]);



}else{
    $sentencia->execute([$REFERENCE, $CODE, $CODETYPE, $NAME, $PRICEBUY,$PRICESELL]);

}
}
```

Comment: `else` en minúscula

Comment: vale vale lo agrego